# What's the proper way to execute some logic in reactor if I'm expecting empty values?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Suppose I have a `Mono<MyObject>` which would be populated by retrieving something from the database or another API. If I got no results from the database or the API returned with an empty body or 404 then I want to execute some logic.

Would I just create a `Mono.error()` and handle it like this

```
Mono<MyObject> myObjectMono = Mono.error(new NotFoundException("Error"));

myObject.doOnError(e -> {
    if (e instanceof NotFoundException) {
        //my logic for responses when database returns 0 rows or api response is empty/404
    }
    else {
        //other logic here for actual errors
    }
}).subscribe(myObject -> {
    //my logic when there's a value
});
```

Or do I use `Mono.empty()`? how do I handle empty though? I know there's `switchIfEmpty()` but I don't really have anything to return and don't want the subscribe logic to execute.

```
Mono<MyObject> myObjectMono = Mono.empty();

myObject.subscribe(myObject -> {
    //my logic when there's a value
});
```

Note that the starting point of this is not Http request so there's no client that I will return the Mono to, for simplicity let's just say it's a scheduled job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are technically correct. The direction to take depends on the conventions established in your project. I'd suggest avoiding exceptions if possible because creating exceptions is a heavy operation because of its stack trace.

If you want to go with `Mono.empty` you can do it like this:

```java
Mono.<String>empty()
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        System.out.println("no response");
        return null;
    }))
    .subscribe(response -> {
        System.out.println("response = " + response);
    });
```

If you want to go with exceptions, you can do it like this:

```java
Mono.<String>error(new RuntimeException(""))
    .subscribe(
        response -> {
            System.out.println("response = " + response);
        },
        error -> {
            System.out.println("error = " + error);
        }
    );
```

or

```java
Mono.<String>error(new RuntimeException(""))
    .doOnError(NotFoundException.class, e -> {
        System.out.println("not found exception: " + e);
    })
    .doOnError(e -> {
        System.out.println("another exception: " + e);
    })
    .subscribe(response -> {
        System.out.println("response = " + response);
    });
```